# Asana: Does API provide user activity logs?

Tags: api, asana

Does the Asana API provide some method of getting user activity logs? I am interested in activity logs and login history logs.Logs could look e.g like "user created a task xyz", "user created a project".

I went through the [documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/) and could not find any such API/REST Endpoint. Does Asana keep such logs 
in their system? If yes then is there a way to get them? If not then is it planned in a future release of the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Asana dev here.)

This isn't something we currently provide. We're working on a system for getting semi-realtime updates to "subscriptions", but we were primarily thinking about subscribing to tasks, projects, workspaces, and so on. Subscribing to a user's activity would be an interesting use case, but one we haven't considered up until now, and one that might be a bit trickier.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Can the `stories` be used somehow to achieve the same effect? My use-case is to get logs of users activity on all task,projects,workspaces and so on. This is more on the lines of audit trail.

Comment: Not easily - you can only get stories on a per-task basis right now. (Technically you can get the stories on a project, but that's actually stories associated with the project *directly* - which no longer exist.) So that probably doesn't help.

Comment: Agnoster - another vote here for adding 'subscriptions' to the API. Specifically, we'd like to subscribe to all stories created for a particular workspace. We could then use target.id to operate on a particular task (if needed).